# Django, Firewalls, Selenium, [Errno 10061], and implicitly_wait()

Tags: python, django, selenium, firewall

So, I'm quite curious about this one.

I've been trying TDD with Django, and took an exercise out of Harry J.W. Percival's book, as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()


    def test_can_start_list_and_retrieve_later(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

        self.assertIn('Django', self.browser.title)
```

Seems simple enough. 
Except I get this failing test:
`error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

So I believe I have some kind of Firewall up (which I'd be thankful if you could direct me to). The most curious thing, however is the following:
If I run the script with this one line omitted, however:          `self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)`

The test curiously passes.

When I fail the test, Django says the following:

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[22/Feb/2016 09:34:38] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1940
```

If this is of any relevance:
OS Is Windows 10
IDE is PyCharm community (so Django is being run in powershell)
Testing framework is Unittest.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome requires a specific driver that matches the Chrome version which is installed on your machine:

```
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
```

Download the chromedrive and copy it to "/path/to/chromedriver" from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Note: For Firefox it's OK to use `webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: I have the latest versions of both Chrome and chromedriver.exe (which is in the directory of the Django project). 

I'm still getting the error. A mismatch would also, as far as I can tell, not explain why "implicitly_waits()" determines whether the test passes or fails.

Perhaps it's related to another error, which is that, when I attempt to add tests to a Django app, I get this:
`ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: That's normal. Simple wait solve A LOT of Selenium otherwise hard to explain issue. A wait is my first go to with Selenium issues.